# @JsonManagedReference causes 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "postal_items")
@Data
public class PostalItem extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "track_number")
    private String trackNumber;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PostalItemType type;

    @Column(name = "recipient_index")
    private Integer recipientIndex;

    @Column(name = "recipient_address")
    private String recipientAddress;

    @Column(name = "recipient_name")
    private String recipientName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postalItem", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Event> events;
```

And entity class associated with this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
@Data
public class Event extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postal_item_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private PostalItem postalItem;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_office_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private PostOffice postOffice;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EventType type;

    @Column(name = "active_status")
    private Boolean activeStatus;
}
```

And I have endpoints in Rest Controller:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<PostalItem>> getAll() {
    List<PostalItem> result = postalItemService.getAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<PostalItem> registrationNewPostalItem(@RequestBody PostalItem postalItem) {
    PostalItem result = postalItemService.registrationNewPostalItem(postalItem);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I got 415 Unsupported Media if I called my POST endpoint. If I change @JsonManagedReference to @JsonIgnore my POST endpoint works ok, but my GET endpoint retuns my PostalItem object without events list. It doesn't suit me.

What can I do for both enpoints works like I need.